# Telegram - post links not opening in web

Tags: telegram

Hello everybody and happy new year :)
I have a problem with opening telegram posts in web. When i do "Copy post link" and open it in browser, it shows:
[image]
Can someone please tell me what's the issue here and how can it be fixed so that the link shows the normal preview? Btw i emailed telegram support and got no answer for the last 2 weeks, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an unorthodox way in my experience to do this. Your specific post link is in this format: `https://t.me/groupname/postID` and you need to copy *postID* to clipboard.

On your PC/ desktop, open that Telegram channel/ group on web browser Chrome as well -> Click hold the scrollbar and drag to previous posts that are before your need-to-open specific post. Choose any post of those and right click choose **Inspect** -> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find and paste the above *postID* to search box and it will move instantly to that post. That's it. The HTML block in tab Elements of newly opened window to the right (or Console window) is in format:

```
<div> class="im_message_outer_wrap hasselect" ng-click="toggleMessage(historyMessage.mid, $event)" data-msg-id="value">
```

And the value of `data-msg-id` is *postID*